# How to get offline message from Tigase pubsub in smack library in android

Tags: android, xmpp, publish-subscribe, tigase

I have integrated Tigase server and I want to store pubsub offline message and retrive all of it when user get online.

For Ex: User_A and User_B is connected, if User_A sends message to User_B and at that time User_B is offline. then **in which location that message goes?** Now User_B is online but he didn't get any message. So **How to retrieve that offline message?**

Does we have to set some properties in init.properties file regarding this?

Here is my init.properties file content which sets the option to configure Tigase server.

```
--comp-class-1 = tigase.muc.MUCComponent
--virt-hosts = test
--user-db-uri = jdbc:mysql://localhost/tigasedb?user=tigase&password=tigase12
--user-db = mysql
--admins = admin@test
--comp-name-4 = message-archive
--comp-name-3 = rest
config-type = --gen-config-def
--comp-name-2 = pubsub
--comp-name-1 = muc
--cluster-mode = false
--sm-plugins = +message-archive-xep-0136,jabber:iq:register,jabber:iq:auth,urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl,urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind,urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session,roster-presence,jabber:iq:privacy,jabber:iq:version,http://jabber.org/protocol/stats,starttls,vcard-temp,http://jabber.org/protocol/commands,jabber:iq:private,urn:xmpp:ping
--debug = server,xmpp.impl,db,pubsub,component,components
--comp-class-4 = tigase.archive.MessageArchiveComponent
--comp-class-3 = tigase.http.rest.RestMessageReceiver
--comp-class-2 = tigase.pubsub.PubSubComponent

# for offline messages
sess-man/plugins-conf/amp/store-limit[L]=200
amp/store-limit[L]=200

sess-man/plugins-conf/amp/msg-pubsub-jid=pubsub.coffeebean.local
sess-man/plugins-conf/amp/msg-pubsub-node=message_sink
sess-man/plugins-conf/amp/msg-pubsub-publisher=sess-admin@test.local
```

All your answer is valuable for me and all will be appreciated.

Please advice.

Thank you.